# Independent text within a box that spans entirely pagewidth as shown, How to?

Tags: tcolorbox, framed

I'm a new user (I used to ask some questions here but it's long time ago) and have a problem about an example box created by `tcolorbox` on `scrbook` class. I would like to ask all guru some questions as following:

1. I want a box to span across the margin as shown in figure no matter what odd/even page. As you can see, box(or blue frame) spans to outer of margin but keep text in text area and still allow to put figure in margin too.

   [image: evenpage example]

   [image: oddpage example]

My MWE.

```
\documentclass[twoside,chapterprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,kantlipsum,multicol}
\usepackage[papersize={21cm,23cm},top=1.8cm, bottom=2cm, outer=7cm, inner=2cm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=5.0cm, marginparsep=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
%The pack­age pro­vides an en­vi­ron­ment for coloured and framed text boxes with a head­ing line
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{wallpaper}

%Define framed box for example problem
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{examplebox}[2][]{breakable,fonttitle=\bfseries, title=\Large{\textbf{Problem.}}~\thetcbcounter #2,#1}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{examplebox}[label={myautocounter},left=1pt]{}
    \begin{marginfigure}[0cm]
        \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}
        \label{fig:dsc4336}
        \caption{I am a figure}
    \end{marginfigure}
I USE MY "EXAMPLEBOX" AS USUAL TEXT AND MARGIN FIGURE WORK AS THEY SHOULD BE BUT I WANT MY EXAMPLE BOX SPREAD OUT TO THE RIGHT MARGIN ON AN ODD PAGE, BREAKABLE, AND SPREAD OUT TO THE LEFT MARGIN ON THE EVEN PAGE.    
\end{examplebox}    

\newpage

\begin{examplebox}[label={myautocounter},left=1pt]{}
    \begin{marginfigure}[0cm]
        \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}
        \label{fig:dsc4336}
        \caption{I am a figure}
    \end{marginfigure}
    I USE MY "EXAMPLEBOX" AS USUAL TEXT AND MARGIN FIGURE WORK AS THEY SHOULD BE BUT I WANT MY EXAMPLE BOX SPREAD OUT TO THE RIGHT MARGIN ON AN ODD PAGE, BREAKABLE, AND SPREAD OUT TO THE LEFT MARGIN ON THE EVEN PAGE.    
\end{examplebox}


\end{document}
```

In my MWE, when I try to expand it, it will take text stretch out to outer margin too. I need to make a breakable box that cover all pagewidth (textwidth+marginparsep+marginparwidth) but still be able to insert text into text area and insert figure into margin area as the same time.

[image: myresult1]

[image]

Any helps, suggestions, comments, are very appreciate.

Have a nice day.

[image: more than 1 page example]

Comment: Welcome! Please provide some code so we can see what you've got, preferably for a minimal but compilable document which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Sorry, but your example is not compilable -- font settings no one else can use, wrong `\label` settings, `\caption` that does appear in floating environments

Comment: @kmmm: I've compiled with `xelatex`

Comment: @Christian: I modified MWE again. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your code cannot be compiled without error, so how can we help when you aren't asking about an error? You need to give us code we can compile to reproduce the problem. If that's an error, it should give the relevant error. If it is the result, it should give the result.

Comment: Note that `geometry` doesn't provide `\marginnote`, as your annotation suggests. Probably it is provided by `marginnote` which `sidenotes` loads. And `\Large` is a switch: it does not take an argument. And I don't know the details, but I'm pretty sure that trying to put a `marginfigure` inside a `tcolorbox` is doomed to fail. Instead, use `tcolorbox`'s facilities for adjusting the width and split the box into two internally, so that you can put the text in one side of the split and the image in the other. You will need to make appropriate choices for the content of (un)breakable boxes.

Comment: Beyond that, I'm actually not entirely clear what this is supposed to do. You want the `examplebox` to take 3 arguments? But you only ever use 2. I can't remember if this is because the box configuration automatically uses the `#3` or not, but check the documentation.

Comment: @kmmm To do that, you would need to layer things so that you put, say, the box in the background when the page is shipped out. It is a bit clearer now you've provided a shorter example.

Comment: @kmmm Or put it all in a box, which is probably easier since you're putting stuff in boxes anyway. However, I doubt you will get this also to be breakable, though perhaps I'm mistaken about `tcolorbox`'s abilities.

Comment: @cfr: Thanks again. If I want to try as you said, do layer thing by put the box in background when the page is shipped out, where should I start to?. (I hope the box will be breakable with this way cause some of my examples are probably 2-3 pages long). Is it possible to get as figure shown?. Any approaches are fine for me.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You're the wiz at this. Is it possible to make this breakable? When I mentioned layering, I was thinking of adding to the ship out hooks as if adding a background and maybe use `tikzmark`s. But this would be problematic in various ways, of course, as you'd need to allow space for the rules and title etc. My sense is that `tcolorbox` may just not support this for breakable boxes, but I don't know the package terribly well. You know it inside out. Any thoughts?

Comment: @cfr: I have to check. `tcolorbox` is some kind of a swiss - knife for many requests, but it is not a 'out-of-the-box' for anything. Breakability (does this word exist at all? ;-)) is difficult in many cases.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Probably not. It is not in OED, at least. However, the word *should* exist or, at least, some word which would mean what I want 'breakability' to mean ;).

Comment: @kmmm You can ping Christian Hupfer here as he's active in these comments (but not in the comments on my answer). However, I already asked him - see last comments above.

Comment: Ok, understood. Since I don't know how to ping him, I'd better wait for his reply here.

Comment: Probably that book uses another tool such as "Indesign" to make the layout more fancy. I'll give it up and try to come up with less complicated layout created by @cfr for my book preparation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you cannot have everything you want. I am almost certain you can't have everything you want without serious fiddlery.

Here are two possible approaches. Both use `tcolorbox` for both the text and marginal image content.

1. This uses a modified form of the `examplebox` environment. The disadvantage is that the marginal image must be specified first on even pages, but second on odd pages i.e. the content switch is not automatic.
2. This switches the content automatically. The disadvantage is that you must use `\tcbsidebyside[example box]{<text column content>}{<marginal image column content>}` to specify the text and marginal image. If you want a title, it is passed as an argument to `example box`.

I illustrate this with 4 examples: one each of each kind on each of an odd and even page.

```
\begin{examplebox}{}
  I use my ``examplebox'' as usual text and margin figure work as they should be but I want my example box spread out to the right margin on an odd page, breakable, and spread out to the left margin on the even page.
  \tcblower
  \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}
  \captionof{figure}{I am figure}\label{fig:example-image}
\end{examplebox}
```

Here, the marginal image goes after `\tcblower` and the text before it. The environment can be passed an optional argument, to override settings locally. The mandatory argument contains the title (here empty).

```
\tcbsidebyside[example box=Title here]{%
  I use my ``examplebox'' as usual text and margin figure work as they should be but I want my example box spread out to the right margin on an odd page, breakable, and spread out to the left margin on the even page.%
}{%
  \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}
  \captionof{figure}{I am a figure}\label{fig:example-image-a}%
}
```

Here, the `example box` style is used, with the title `Title here`. The text goes in the first mandatory argument; the marginal image goes in the second.

```
\newpage
```

So ends our odd page.

```
\begin{examplebox}{}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-b}
  \captionof{figure}{I am b figure}\label{fig:example-image-b}
  \tcblower
  I use my ``examplebox'' as usual text and margin figure work as they should be but I want my example box spread out to the right margin on an odd page, breakable, and spread out to the left margin on the even page.
\end{examplebox}
```

Here, the marginal image goes before `\tcblower`, while the text goes after. Arguments as before.

```
\tcbsidebyside[example box]{% with no title
  I use my ``examplebox'' as usual text and margin figure work as they should be but I want my example box spread out to the right margin on an odd page, breakable, and spread out to the left margin on the even page.%
}{%
  \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-c}
  \captionof{figure}{I am c figure}\label{fig:example-image-c}%
}
```

Here, the `example box` style is invoked without an argument, so the title is empty in this case. As before, the text is specified in the first mandatory argument; the marginal image in the second. As we are on an even page, this order will be automatically switched when typesetting i.e. the marginal image will be set in the left of the box and the text in the right.

Hence ends our even page.

The first approach with the `examplebox` environment has been modified to use a custom counter, in order to illustrate how the second approach could be integrated into a single numbering sequence, in case you want to use a mixture of such approaches. If not, you could more conveniently stick to `tcbcounter`.

[image: four boxes]

```
\documentclass[twoside,chapterprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe, papersize={21cm,23cm},top=1.8cm, bottom=2cm, outer=7cm, inner=2cm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=5.0cm, marginparsep=0.5cm]{geometry}% I guess you know this package tramples wantonly on KOMA-script's careful typographic design?!
%The pack­age pro­vides an en­vi­ron­ment for coloured and framed text boxes with a head­ing line
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\NewTColorBox
[%
  use counter=mytcbcounter, 
]{examplebox}{ O{} +m }{%
  breakable, 
  toggle enlargement=evenpage, 
  grow to right by=\marginparwidth+\marginparsep, 
  sidebyside, 
  lower separated=false, 
  if odd page={lefthand width=\textwidth-2.5mm-2pt, before lower app=\centering,}{righthand width=\textwidth-2.5mm-2pt, before upper app=\centering},
  boxrule=.5mm, 
  boxsep=1mm, 
  left=1pt,
  right=1pt, 
  sidebyside gap=\marginparsep+2mm+2pt, 
  fonttitle=\bfseries\Large, 
  title={Problem~\themytcbcounter #2}, 
  #1,
}

\tcbset{%
  example box/.style={
    breakable, 
    toggle enlargement=evenpage, 
    grow to right by=\marginparwidth+\marginparsep, 
    sidebyside, 
    lower separated=false, 
    if odd page={lefthand width=\textwidth-2.5mm-2pt, before lower app=\centering,}{before upper app=\centering, righthand width=\textwidth-2.5mm-2pt, sidebyside switch},% p.125 of manual
    boxrule=.5mm, 
    boxsep=1mm, 
    left=1pt,
    right=1pt,      
    sidebyside gap=\marginparsep+2mm+2pt, 
    fonttitle=\bfseries\Large, 
    code=\refstepcounter{mytcbcounter},
    title={Problem~\themytcbcounter{} #1}, 
  },
}

\newcounter{mytcbcounter}
\setcounter{mytcbcounter}{0}
\numberwithin{mytcbcounter}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{examplebox}{}
  I use my ``examplebox'' as usual text and margin figure work as they should be but I want my example box spread out to the right margin on an odd page, breakable, and spread out to the left margin on the even page.
  \tcblower
  \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}
  \captionof{figure}{I am figure}\label{fig:example-image}
\end{examplebox}


\tcbsidebyside[example box=Title here]{%
  I use my ``examplebox'' as usual text and margin figure work as they should be but I want my example box spread out to the right margin on an odd page, breakable, and spread out to the left margin on the even page.%
}{%
  \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}
  \captionof{figure}{I am a figure}\label{fig:example-image-a}%
}

\newpage

\begin{examplebox}{}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-b}
  \captionof{figure}{I am b figure}\label{fig:example-image-b}
  \tcblower
  I use my ``examplebox'' as usual text and margin figure work as they should be but I want my example box spread out to the right margin on an odd page, breakable, and spread out to the left margin on the even page.
\end{examplebox}

\tcbsidebyside[example box]{% with no title
  I use my ``examplebox'' as usual text and margin figure work as they should be but I want my example box spread out to the right margin on an odd page, breakable, and spread out to the left margin on the even page.%
}{%
  \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-c}
  \captionof{figure}{I am c figure}\label{fig:example-image-c}%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow!. That's awesome. Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help. It's work but like you said, we can't get everything as we want. The box is unbreakable through the second page.

Comment: @kmmm Glad it helps. I know it doesn't do everything you hoped for. I think that may not be possible (without rewriting fundamental things - certainly well beyond my abilities). There are limitations on what can be made `breakable` in `tcolorbox`. See the manual for details (though the details aren't all grouped together, unfortunately.)  A `tcolorbox` expert could tell you for sure, but `breakable` may just be ignored here if the option isn't compatible with the rest.

Comment: @kmmm You could try asking in chat. Christian Hupfer is a real wiz with this package, for example.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and time. At least, we knew that using tcbsidebyside will make the box unbreakable. How to ask Christian Hupfer in chat as you mentioned?.

Comment: cfr: What's the different between normal \newtcolorbox and your \NewTColorBox ?

Comment: @kmmm `\NewTColorBox` uses `xparse` and is more powerful. See the manual for full details of the additional features supported.